# Is there a way to make XCode's "Show Invisibles" any less typographically eyeball-assaulting?

Tags: xcode, settings, xcode4.5, user-experience, typography

I mean, it *appears* to offer control over this -- but (at least as per my personal, fairly exhaustive investigation) it's Potemkin UX:

[image: Invisibles Should Be Seen And Not Heard]

... the "Invisibles" color field doesn't actually affect the invisibles (which is that a joke? Like it controls the color of something else which is actually invisible??); the color field that does will not do so without simultaneously lending the tint you ascribe to it to the entirety of the rest of the documents' unhighlighted text.

I'm patient and flexible enough to either deal a text editors' quirks and I am nerdy enough to hack through said quirks when my patience and flexibility are depleted -- I have a haunted museum of 1990s-era elisp snippets and X configuration dotfiles that speak to this -- but I find these dysfunctionally Klein-bottlesque options flummoxing. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working now. You can set a lighter color for Invisibles color for light theme.

In my Xcode 11, I can set Invisibles color from `Preferences` -> `Fonts & Colors` -> `Source Editor`. There are some configurable items.

[image]

The code looks perfect now.

[image: code with invisibles]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, way back then and now – thanks!